# Finding General Expression from recursion

Tags: mathematica, computability, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to find a general expression from a recursion.

Here it goes:
$(x+i)P_i = (i+1)P_{i+1} + \frac{x}{2} P_{i-1}$

$i$ goes from $0$ to $S$.

How can I calculate a generic $P_i$ in terms of $P_0$? So, if $P_i = C \times P_0$, what is $P_0$?

Is it possible to solve this in Mathematica? What is the function I'm looking for?

You can assume $P_0 = 1$.

Thanks.

**[UPDATE]**

I am  not quite sure if this would help. I started from $P_0$ and have the following equations:
$P_{1}=P_{0}x$

$P_{2}=P_{0}(\frac{1}{2!})(x^2+\frac{x}{2})$

$P_{3}=P_{0}(\frac{1}{3!})(x^3+\frac{3x^2}{2}+x)$

$P_{4}=P_{0}(\frac{1}{4!})(x^4+3x^3+\frac{19x^2}{4}+3x)$

$P_{5}=P_{0}(\frac{1}{5!})(x^5+5x^4+\frac{55x^3}{4}+20x^2+12x)$

I tried to find polynomials that will represent above, but I could not find one.
These are basically balance equations for a two dimensional markov chain. I solved it numerically, but I want to have a analytical solution as well.

Comment: Isn't the issue here that you have bidirectional recursion so you have to know the value of both $P_0$ and $P_L$?

Comment: @Verbeia: Or just any two $P_i$s...

Comment: @Simon - yes, and I meant $S$ not $L$ anyway. Not sure where I got $L$ from. :-/

Comment: I just updated the question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ok, so there isn't any dependence on $P_{i+1}$ after all. Have a look at the [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RSolve.html) function.

Comment: Your new edit is a very special choice of $P_1$. It's equivalent to choosing the initial condition $P_{-1} = 0$ (and $P_0$ unfixed)...

Comment: Let me name the polynomial sequences(excluding $1/x!$ )as $C_1, C_2 C_3, C_4, C_5$ $C_2/C_1$ = $x+0.5$ $C_3/C_2$ = $x+1$ remainder: $0.5x$ $C_4 / C_3$ = $x+1.5$ remainder: $1.5x^2+1.5x$ $C_5 / C_4$ = $x+2$ remainder: $3x^3 + 7.5x^2 +6x$ Is this a hyper-geometric series? I am novice in this.

Comment: A [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Notation) can be defined as a exponential generating function of a hypergeometric series. This does not really correspond to what you have above... Although, maybe you mean something different. (Also, these types of comments aren't really appropriate as answers in this site)

Comment: @sosruko: I've merged your old and new accounts. If you wish, you can now put the above comment as an edit to your question. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is no, it's not possible to solve in Mathematica and probably no closed form (in terms of standard functions) exists.

Using the initial condition $P_{-1}=0$ so that $P_1 = x P_0$ as in your edit, we can try to solve the recurrence relation using Mathematica

```
soln = RSolve[P[i] == ((-1 + i + x) P[-1 + i])/i - (x P[-2 + i])/(2 i) 
           && P[-1] == 0 && P[0] == P0, P, i][[1]]

{P -> DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, n}, 
  {x y[n] - 2 (1 + n + x) y[1 + n] + (4 + 2 n) y[2 + n] == 0, 
   y[-1] == 0, y[0] == P0}]]}
```

It returns an `DifferenceRoot` object, which is just the original relation wrapped up in something that knows how to do various calculations.

For example, as you noted in your edit, the result takes the form

$$ \begin{align}
P_i = \frac{x}{i!}P_0 R_i(x)\,, \quad 
R_i(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a_{i,j} x^j\,,\\
\text{ where }
a_{i,i-1}=1 \text{ and } a_{i,j}=0 \text{ for } i\geq j
\end{align}$$

We can produce the $R_i(x)$, up to some factors of 2, with Mathematica

```
Table[(i! 2^Floor[i/2])/(P0 x) P[i], {i, 1, 5}] /. soln // Expand

{1, 1 + 2 x, 2 + 3 x + 2 x^2, 12 + 19 x + 12 x^2 + 4 x^3, 
 48 + 80 x + 55 x^2 + 20 x^3 + 4 x^4}
```

If we extract the coefficients of the polynomials $R_i(x)$ using

```
Reverse[CoefficientList[#, x]] & /@ %
```

then we can feed them for various $i$ into 
[The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/)
to see if they match any known pattern.
Unfortunately, they don't. So the chances are, there are no simple variation of a common polynomial sequence that reproduce the $R_i(x)$.

Note that the higher order polynomial have more complicated coefficients.
Which you can look at by running
`Map[Times @@ (Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[#]) &, %, {2}]`
on the previous output. Some large primes arrive pretty quickly.

Interestingly though, up to the factors of 2, the sequence $R_i(1)$ corresponds to [A005650](http://oeis.org/A005650) and $R_i(2)$ matches [A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522). However, $R_i(3)$ and higher do not seem to match anything in OEIS. That said, maybe these clues could be of some help in finding a closed form.

Finally, we can find a recurrence relation for the $a_{i,j}$ by plugging the general form of the solution into the original relation. It yields
$$ a_{i+1,j} = i a_{i,j} + a_{i,j-1} - \frac{i}{2}a_{i-1,j-1}\,,
\text{ where } a_{i,j}=0 \text{ for } j<0 \text{ or } j\geq i\ .
$$

See also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32937/how-to-find-guess-a-polynomial-sequence
Which reminds me, maybe a generating function approach would get somewhere.
Have you read [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) and [A=B](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html)?

Comment: Substituting $x=1$ gives http://oeis.org/A000681